# Find numbers that are palindromic in consecutive number bases

Tags: python, performance, beginner, python-3.x, mathematics

> I want to generate numbers which are palindromic in three or more
>   consecutive number bases in the most optimal, fastest way (up to some
>   range). I do not count trivial one digit palindromes.
>
> *(When I say 3 or more, I mean 3 and 4, as it is not known if a solution for 4 or more bases exists)*

I'm basically generating palindromes in number base \$b\$, and then converting and checking whether it is also palindromic in \$b+1, b+2, \dots\$

Are there any ways to noticeably speed up my code?

---

```
# Converts any number n to any base b (*), Source: [1]
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/5821790
def numberToBase(n, b):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        n //= b
    return digits[::-1]

# Generates palindromes in base b (*), Source: [2]
# https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494909
def palgen(b):
    i = 1
    while True:
        ii = b * i
        r = range(i, ii)
        for j in r:
            s = numberToBase(j, b)
            yield s + s[-2::-1]
        for j in r:
            s = numberToBase(j, b)
            yield s + s[::-1]
        i = ii

# Checks if the list is palindromic, Source: [3]
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340347/5821790
def isPalindrome(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    return s[0] == s[-1] and isPalindrome(s[1:-1])

# converts number in base b (*) to integer
def listToInt(digitList, base):
    l = len(digitList)
    value = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(digitList):
        value += val*base**(l-i-1)
    return value

# returns current time
def getTime():
    return strftime("( %H:%M:%S )", gmtime())


###################################################################
# Searches for numbers palindromic in 3 or more consecutive bases #
###################################################################

from time import gmtime, strftime
from math import sqrt, floor

bound = 10**8                       # numbers up to
baseBound = floor(sqrt(bound))      # bases up to (bound, can be improved)
print(getTime(), "Starting with:" ,baseBound, bound)

for b in range(2, baseBound):
    for i, s in enumerate(palgen(b), 1):

        # convert palindrome s_b to integer x and check if out of bound
        x = listToInt(s, b)
        if (x > bound): break

        if (len(s) > 1): # one digit palindromes do not count (trivial)

            # checks if the palindrome x is also palindromic in more bases
            if (isPalindrome(numberToBase(x, b+1))):
                if (isPalindrome(numberToBase(x, b+2))):
                    print(getTime(), b, x, len(s))

                    if (isPalindrome(numberToBase(x, b+3))):
                        print(b, x, len(s), "*** AT LEAST FOUR IN A ROW ***")
```

> What are some things here that can be improved, and how, following
>   good practice?

*(Beside mathematical aspects which include the bound above which no more examples are found, the fact that only odd digit length palindromes form consecutive triples, and the facts that some examples follow a pattern that can be generated.)*

Sources: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28666223/5821790) [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494909) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340347/5821790)

Outputs: [[10^9, ~ 3 hours: 1200 bases]](https://pastebin.com/aaZyBCA8) and [[10^12, ~ 3 hours: 100 bases]](https://pastebin.com/P6cWjSbP)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python may be a faster way to reverse strings (and thus check palindromity). You might also consider generating palindromes in the highest base first and then looking at `b-1`, `b-2` etc. You might also be able to use "mod" to discard multiples of a given base (depending on how you treat strings that end in "0").

Comment: Avoid to redefine a built-in function like [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: @BarryCarter My palindromes are stored and handled as lists of integers, not exactly strings, but I can still apply the same thing on it: and turns out my recursive function seems to be roughly the same speed compared to something like `s == s[::-1]` , If I'm not mistaken? Also, I'm not sure how you meant to discard duplicates exactly?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Renamed it to `listToInt`

Comment: @Vepir It is recommended to respect PEP8 naming convention, so I prefer: `list_to_int`.

Comment: Discard multiples, not duplicates. For example, a multiple of 5 will end in "0" in base 5. Depending on how you define palindrome, it might be impossible for that number to be a palindrome.

Comment: @BarryCarter Did you meant to optimize the step where the palindrome is converted to bases b+1,b+2 and checked for being palindrome again?( >> If the number x is a multiple of b+1 or b+2 then do not check it since it ends with "0" - and a palindrome/number can't start with zero?); Just ran a quick test: this actually just discards a very small number of palindromes per number base - and the value [discards / total_palindromes] tends to 0 as the  number base grows. And actually using `(if not (x % (b+1) == 0 or x % (b+2) == 0))` in the `while` loop, slows it down rather than making it faster.

Comment: Only significant discarding of palindromes I believe would be, if we could generate only palindromes which are palindromic in two consecutive bases, and then just checking for a third.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 5 → 3.

Comment: @200_success Why roll back? The part of the code that the answer is talking about was not edited. And that edit was done even before the answer, If I recall it correctly. I don't understand your roll back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small performance improvement is possible in the `listToInt` function,
by using multiplications only instead of exponentiation
(which is [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)):

```
# converts number in base b list representation to integer
def listToInt(digitList, base):
    value = 0
    for val in digitList:
        value = value * base + val
    return value
```

On my computer this reduced the time to compute the results for
\$ b = 1270, \ldots, 1286 \$ from 130 to 101 seconds.

Comment: I'll be accepting this as there seems to be no other improvements lying near by.

Answer (score 0):

This `numberToBase` function can be defined as:

`def numberToBase(n, b):
    return int(str(n), b))`

Also as stated in comment `isPalindrom` can be defined as:

`def isPalindrom(s):
    return s == s[::-1]`

This may speed it up a bit.

Comment: You didn't even read what my `numberToBase` does; your definition of it seems to do the reverse, but not  even that really as perhaps you also aren't aware that `int(str, int)` only has range for number bases in [2,36], am I not mistaken?